# Sub Query or Nested. I really dont know. maybe neither

Tags: mysql, nested, pivot

OK, I may have missed this in the search, but I am unsure of what I am looking for. I have a couple of tables that I need ti generate mailing labels from. Main table has name and surname. Then a second table has multiple rows for data like phon-123415324, address 1- 1 james st etc...There is also a table that bind the data. Here is an example result and the query.

```
SELECT
users.name,
users.surname,
details.`field`,
details.value
FROM
users
Inner Join details ON details.user_id = users.id
Inner Join bookings ON bookings.guest_id = users.id
WHERE
bookings.sub_event_id =  '78'
```

---

```
NAME, SURNAME, field,  value
David   Oden    title   Mr
David   Oden    sex Male
David   Oden    mobile  0534600594
David   Oden    company Fterns Group
David   Oden    position    
David   Oden    address_1   Cnr wtrewr Rd & wert St
David   Oden    address_2   
David   Oden    suburb  wertt Mile wertw
David   Oden    state   MAS
David   Oden    postcode    14113
David   Oden    country USA
```

WHAT I need I all the data i 1 row to export to excel for mailing labels. Sorry if this is really dumb. I have spent about 4 hours researching with no luck.

I need the type to be a column header and the value to be the data.

Shoud read

```
Title | Name | Surname | Mobile | Company | Address etc.....

MR | David | Oden | 0534600594 | Fterns Group | etc....
```

Any help would be appreciated/

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a `PIVOT` function but unfortunately MySQL does not have a `PIVOT`, so you will have to replicate it use an aggregate function an a `CASE` statement.  If you know the values that you need to include in the query, then you can hard-code them similar to the following:

```
select 
  min(case when d.field = 'title' then d.value end) as Title,
  u.name,
  u.surname,
  min(case when d.field = 'sex' then d.value end) as Sex,
  min(case when d.field = 'mobile' then d.value end) as Mobile,
  min(case when d.field = 'company' then d.value end) as Company,
  min(case when d.field = 'position' then d.value end) as Position,
  min(case when d.field = 'address_1' then d.value end) as Address_1,  
  min(case when d.field = 'address_2' then d.value end) as Address_2,  
  min(case when d.field = 'suburb' then d.value end) as suburb,  
  min(case when d.field = 'state' then d.value end) as State,
  min(case when d.field = 'postcode' then d.value end) as Postcode,
  min(case when d.field = 'country' then d.value end) as country
from users u
left join details d
  on u.id = d.id
left join bookings b
  on u.id = b.guest_id
where b.sub_event_id = 78
group by u.name, u.surname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1d4e/3)

But if you have an unknown number of columns or if the value will change, then you will want to perform this dynamically, then you should read the following article on prepared statements:

[Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

Your code would look like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'min(case when d.field = ''',
      d.field,
      ''' then d.value end) AS ',
      d.field
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from users u
left join details d
  on u.id = d.d_id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.name,
                    u.surname, ', @sql, ' 
                  from users u
                  left join details d
                    on u.id = d.d_id
                  left join bookings b
                    on u.id = b.guest_id
                  where b.sub_event_id = 78
                  group by u.name, u.surname');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1d4e/9)

Comment: He, Been a long time, but thanks for the help on this. Managed to get it going... Appreciated,.

Comment: @user1679844 happy to help, be sure to accept any answers that are helpful via the check mark on the left.  It will also help future visitors.